# Log in to secured https website with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to automate my daily tasks by VBA script automatically login into my bank account and returning some data from the website. However, I cannot write such macro which could login in into this website - https://online.mbank.pl/pl/Login.

I wrote the following macro which works well with "normal" websites such google (based on input box IDs), but does not work with bank websites returning, the following error:

> Run-time error 424: Object required

[image]

Below code for google.com:

```
Sub LoginHttps()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = 1000
        .Width = 1250
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=N-TZVaPMAdCv8wf19aH4Bw&gws_rd=cr&fg=1"

        Do While .Busy Or Not .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        .Document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = "input"
    End With
End Sub
```

and code for bank website which generates an 424 error:

```
Sub LoginHttps()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = 1000
        .Width = 1250
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://online.mbank.pl/pl/Login"

        Do While .Busy Or Not .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        .Document.getElementById("userID").Value = "input"
    End With
End Sub
```

I am wondering whether there is any method to access these input boxes by VBA or it is secured by bank programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three sequential checks: first `Do ... Loop` is usual check of IE state, second - document completeness check, and third - target element check, which returns `Null` for me while target node not ready (instead of `HTMLInputElement` object when it does).

```
Sub LoginHttps()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = 1000
        .Width = 1250
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://online.mbank.pl/pl/Login"
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until .document.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop
        Do While IsNull(.document.getElementById("userID")): DoEvents: Loop
        .document.getElementById("userID").Value = "input"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bond, I've described the return of `TypeName()` in my answer. Generally `.getElementById()` doesn't generate error if the sought node doesn't exist, it just return non-object (error usually caused by `Set` keyword). BTW, I've checked that particularly in this code checking `.document.readyState` has no effect, and checking `TypeName()` suspends the execution not to get error.

Comment: I noticed that, too, after testing it. You may be able to make it even more generic by using `Do While TypeName(.document.getelementbyid("userID")) = "Null"`.

Comment: @omegastripes, thanks for your solution. But I have one more question. What can I do if input box are not defined by seperate "ID", but only by "class name" or "class", as follows `<input name="username" size="16" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" class="editbox" type="text"></input>`. I found GetElementsByName method but how I can to address the one element from elements it returns (even assuming that it returns one element).

Comment: @omegastripes, do you mean I should add this question at the end of the first one?

Comment: @azera, if you find that your new question is related to the initial question - why not? Otherwise try to find answer yourself and if not - create new question.

Comment: @omegastripes, ok I got it. I'll try tommorow to find something more about GetElementsByName/GetElementsByClassName methods and I'll post the question if I do not succeed. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE is returning a "ready" state before the whole page is loaded. The site may be using AJAX to load additional content or doing some sort of redirect. Try adding a small delay before checking to see if the page is ready. For example:

```
.Navigate "https://online.mbank.pl/pl/Login"

' Small delay...
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

Do While .Busy Or Not .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

.Document.getElementById("userID").Value = "input"
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this with other bank websites which also did not work before.

Comment: IMO delay in cases like that would be either unreliable (for small delay) or excessively long (for long delay).