# getElementById Error Object requried

Tags: vbscript

I am using `getElementById` to get ID node value but I am getting an error.
Is any one can help me to remove this error.

```vb
Dim oExec()
ReDim oExec(NbParks)
Dim ParkName()
ReDim ParkName(NbParks)
Dim ParkUrl()
ReDim ParkUrl(NbParks)
Dim ParkFilesArray()
Dim Ippark

Ippark = document.getElementById("IP00").FIRSTCHILD.nodeValue  '<- error occurs here

For i=0 To NbParks - 1
    ParkUrl(i)=xmlLocation.getElementsByTagName("Park").Item(i).getAttribute("url")
    ParkName(i)=xmlLocation.getElementsByTagName("Park").Item(i).getAttribute("name")
    Set oExec(i)=wsh.Exec("wscript " & Chr(34) & cheminbase & "\read.vbs" & Chr(34) & " " & i & " " & ParkUrl(i))

    TD id="IP00" style="width:80.5%" colspan="1" class=""titleBar"" align=""center"">" & "175.111.14.26/16.6.11.9246/nc2" &
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the complete, unaltered error message. Without that it's unlikely someone would be able to even guess at what might cause the issue.

Comment: thank you Mr Ansgar Wiechers 
as you mention error cause kindly also give me solution for this   Ippark = document.getElementById("IP00").FIRSTCHILD.nodeValue

Comment: Willing to bet you haven't set `document` to be the necessary object.  You need a `Set document = ` somewhere above the code you've provided before you can access the elements list from it.

Comment: Since you havn't posted the entire code, the only solutuon I can suggest is to make additional checks after `.Navigate` method invoked, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32170074/2165759) example.