# VBA pulling prices from different HTML classes

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

Im looking to create a VBA script which checks a website and pulls the price from the class. My issue there are 2 potential classes ".kuSalePrice kuSpecialPrice" and ".kuSalePrice". I created the below to check if the class ".kuSalePrice" exists and if not, the second class and output the price.

I am getting the following error on the line below

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lRow).Value = result2.innerText
```

> "Object variable or with block variable not set"

```
Sub PriceCheck()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim result As IHTMLElement
Dim result2 As IHTMLElement
Dim url As String
Dim lRow As Long

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True
lRow = 2
url = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & lRow).Value

Do Until url = ""
    ie.navigate url

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set doc = ie.document

    Set result = doc.querySelector(".SalePrice")


    If IsObject(doc.querySelector(".SalePrice")) Then
    MsgBox "does exsist"
    Set result2 = result

    Else
    MsgBox "doesnt exsist"
    Set result2 = doc.querySelector(".SalePrice SpecialPrice")

    End If

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lRow).Value = result2.innerText

    lRow = lRow + 1
    url = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & lRow).Value
Loop

Cells.Replace What:="£", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Try to implement the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170074/2165759) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47084865/2165759).

Comment: "IsObject returns True even if the variable has been set to Nothing. Use error trapping to be sure that an object reference is valid" - from the VBA reference for `IsObject` found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/isobject-function)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I would try something like :

```
If IsObject(doc.querySelector(".SalePrice")) Then
    Set result = doc.querySelector(".SalePrice")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lRow).Value = result.innerText
ElseIf IsObject(doc.querySelector(".SalePrice SpecialPrice")) Then
    Set result = doc.querySelector(".SalePrice SpecialPrice")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lRow).Value = result.innerText
End If
```